# how to get row and column value of different parameter in r?

Tags: r

I am stuck with one problem.

I have data set

```
v1   v2   v3  v4
VL   M    H   M
M    H    L   L
M    M    M   H
VH   H    H   VL
```

column name is v1 v2 v3  for every row values will change with five parameters. M-medium, L-Low, VL-very low, VH-very high, H-HIGH.

I want higher column and row value.that means if M count is higher in first row, first row high value is M. if row  have two higher value then taken both as higher value. Same way with the columns. If there all have same count select All as higher.

output:
row higher value

```
A   B
1   M
2   L
3   M
4   H
```

cloumn higher value

```
A    B
V1   M
V2   M,H
V3   H
V4   M,L,H,VL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks valid:

```
ff = function(x) {
   tab = table(x)
   paste0(names(tab)[which(tab == max(tab))], collapse = ", ")
}
apply(DF, 2, ff)  #for columns
#           v1            v2            v3            v4 
#          "M"        "H, M"           "H" "H, L, M, VL" 
apply(DF, 1, ff)  #for rows
#[1] "M" "L" "M" "H"
```

Where `DF`:

```
DF = read.table(text = 'v1   v2   v3  v4
VL   M    H   M
M    H    L   L
M    M    M   H
VH   H    H   VL', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```